# define schema fro array of struct

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a dataframe whose printSchema gives this schema :

```
|-- BeginStep: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _Code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
```

Any idea how to define a structType fro this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val schema = new StructType()
.add(
    StructField(
        "BeginStep",
        ArrayType(
            new StructType()
            .add(StructField("_Code",StringType,true))
            .add(StructField("_VALUE",StringType,true))
            ,true
        ),true)
    )
```

```
scala> schema.printTreeString

root
 |-- BeginStep: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _Code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the `schema` as below

```
val schema = StructType(
    List(
      StructField("BeginStep", ArrayType(
        StructType(
          List(
            StructField("_CODE", StringType),
            StructField("_VALUE", StringType)
          )
        )
      ))
    )
  )
```